# Is there a command in suse linux just like "yum provides <command>" to find which package includes this command?

Tags: yum, zypper

**As title!**
When I invoked a command in sles15，indicated as follow
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkD2P.png)

How can I find what package should I install？

Did zypper have the similar command as 'yum provides'?
zypper subcommand what-provides just search installed packages!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please ask in SuperUser.  Stack Overflow is for programming questions.